# C++ Program crashes

Tags: c++

Why is the following program stuck in a following loop after "Done!", and then ends with a crash?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

struct stringy{
    char * str;
    int ct;
};

void set(stringy & s, const char * cs);
void show(const char * s, int times=1);
void show(const stringy & s, int times=1);

int main(){
    stringy beany;
    char testing[] = "Reality isn't what it is used to be.";
    set(beany, testing);
    show(beany);
    show(beany, 2);
    testing[0] = 'D';
    testing[1] = 'u';

    show(testing);
    show(testing, 3);
    show("Done!");

    return 0;
}

void set(stringy & s, const char * cs){
    s.ct = strlen(cs);
    strcpy(s.str, cs);
}

void show(const char * s, int times){
    while (times-- > 0){
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}

void show(const stringy & s, int times){
    show(s.str, times);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's stuck in an endless loop?

Comment: Because reality isn't what it is used to be.

Comment: Is it printing `"Done!"` over and over? Or just hanging?

Comment: It gets stuck for a couple of second, then crashes.

Comment: @ultimatebuster:  By the time you get to the `show("Done!");` call, your program has already exhibitted undefined behavior.  Fix the earlier errors first, before trying to tackle whatever defects there may (or may not) be in `Show()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocate memory for string before copying

```
void set(stringy & s, const char * cs){
    s.ct = strlen(cs);
    s.str = new char[s.ct+1];
    strcpy(s.str, cs);
}
```

Free the memory

```
delete[] beany.str;
```

Comment: Yeah i realized that and did that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You do a lot of `strcpy`, but where are your `malloc`s?!

If you use C++ you should *really* use std::string to avoid things like this.

Comment: I know, I'm just learning and the book's exercise is asking me specifically to use `char *`

Comment: There are no needs for mallocs. He's basically pointing to char arrays that are within the code-segment.

Comment: @Vita: Bo was talking about `s.str`. The pointer is uninitialized so the behavior of strcpying a buffer to it is undefined. This is very likely the reason for the crash.

Comment: @Ultimatebuster - Use another book, perhaps? :-)

Comment: @Vite:  See my answer.  I point out the wild pointer explicity.

Answer (score 1):

A variety of problems:

```
struct stringy{
    char * str;
    int ct;
};

// [snip]

stringy beany;
char testing[] = "Reality isn't what it is used to be.";
set(beany, testing);

void set(stringy & s, const char * cs){
    s.ct = strlen(cs);
    strcpy(s.str, cs);
}
```

At the point of the call to `strcpy`, `s.str` is just a wild pointer.  It doesn't point to anything valid.

This might be homework, but if not you should be using `std::string` instead of raw `char*`s.  If you need to use raw `char*`s, then you need to allocate the space -- using `new` or, better yet, a smart pointer -- to which the pointers point.  You can't just copy a string in to hyperspace and expect it to work.

Comment: Not exactly homework, I'm learning on my own so I assigned it to myself.

Comment: Also, there is a grammar mistake in testing. [evil laugh]

Comment: @ravloony:  What grammar mistake?

Comment: @John - It is not a C++ grammar mistake, but bad English in the text that  is copied. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I get a segmentation fault when I run your program. You need to allocate memory for s.str before the call to strcpy.

Comment: A different strategy is of course to use a fixed length buffer, e.g. char str[64];

Answer (score -1):

```
 void set(stringy & s, const char * cs){
     s.ct = strlen(cs);
     strcpy(s.str, cs);
 }
```

s.str is unallocated. You need to do a

```
s.str = malloc(s.ct);
```

Comment: `malloc(s.ct + 1)`, or just `strdup`.

Comment: -1: for malloc in C++ code.  Use `new` and `delete`, not `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: On the other hand, apart form the first 3 lines, this isn't _really_ C++ at all...